# How to connect Power Bi report builder v15.6 to power bi report server

Tags: powerbi, report, power-bi-report-server, on-premises-instances, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have downloaded the latest Power Bi report builder v15.6
I want to save the report to the Power Bi Report Server which I have set up in the PC. Normally when we do a save as , it gives a option for the Report Server which I am unable to find in Current Power Bi Report Builder

[image]

Whereas if you see in the Microsoft Report Builder, there is a option for the same

[image]

Now when I try to do use the Microsoft Report Builder and save the report in Power bi report server, I am receiving some version error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Power BI Report Builder is not for Power BI Reporting Server. Power BI Report Builder is for Premium Capacities that support Paginated Reports, [so you deploy to the service not a server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/report-builder-power-bi).

Power BI Report Server, only supports reports built by Power BI Desktop for Report Server
You'll be able to use paginated reports with the new Power BI Premium per user license.

If you want paginated report, then installing SQL Server Reporting Services is your best option and using Report Builder, as this is the same technology as paginated reports, and what is Power BI Report Builder is based on.